# How to store the zeros at the end of a binary sequence into a BitSet (Java)?

Tags: java, data-structures, binary, bitset

My aim is to store a binary sequence into a BitSet as it is, without loosing the track of any zero at the end of the sequence and further retrieve the sequence from the BitSet in the same order.

Example: if there is a sequence s = 00110100,
**all the 8 bits of the sequence must be stored in the BitSet and must be retrieved in the same order.**

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Why do you want to force a `BitSet` to do something it is not designed to do? A bitset doesn't care if the values you set are 001101 or 1101 or 000001101. If you want to read the 5th bit from the right, just do that.

Comment: @RealSkeptic its not the XY problem, I am doing some cryptography related work that requires the number of 0s and 1s  to be counted to perform calculations, hence both 0 and 1 are significant to me................by the way thanx 4 ur advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#BitSet(int)

You will not loose any info if you ignore leading zeros, just keep track of number of bits you read. I guess you need to be able to print leading zeroes. You can do that by padding with 0s in printf function.

String.format("%05d", yournumber); this will give you 5 leading zeroes.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html